# Table_Calendar how to filter only the day of the month

Tags: flutter

I am currently filling a beautiful Table Calendar (https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar)

To get my data I currently doing this:

```
            Firestore.instance
              .collection('nurseries')
              .document(widget._favoriteNurseryId)
              .collection('events')
              .orderBy('eventDateStart')
              .snapshots(),
```

I need to find a solution to filter data only for displayed month on the screen. For now i fetch all events on database. It cost me too many firestore Reads.

Comment: Hey, can you include Firestore structure on how you had saved events ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**
I initially misunderstood the question. To get start and end date on the calendar you can either listen to on `OnSelectedDaySelected` and determine start and end dates based on calendar format.

Or

Listen to `OnCalendarCreated` and `OnVisibleDaysChaned` event callbacks to get start and end dates on the calendar.

Refer: https://pub.dev/documentation/table_calendar/latest/table_calendar/table_calendar-library.html

Sounds like you need to query the data instead of fetching everything. Following query should work:

```
Firestore.instance
  .collection('nurseries')
  .document(widget._favoriteNurseryId)
  .collection('events')
  .orderBy('eventDateStart')
  .startAt('startDate')   // startAfter
  .endAt('endDate')     // endBefore
  .snapshots()
```

Comment: Ah I see, But you can listen to `onDaySelected` callback and based on calendar format just use start and end of the month/day/2 week for query.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand you question well but, I think you search about

FieldValue.serverTimestamp()

Try it

Comment: everytime people open calendar, all the events will are loader and cost me a lot of firestore reads. I only want to fetch the current displayed month. When the user go to next month it will fetch next month data.